# Button with image - How to set the button size

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a button on top of which I have put an image. How can I set the size of the button to be same as the size of the image? Please note I cannot use "Height" and "Width" property because my form is suppose to resize

```
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click" >
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                        <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication5;component/myimage.png" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click" Width="{Binding ElementName=img,Path=Width}" Height="{Binding ElementName=img,Path=Height}">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                    <Image x:Name="img" Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication5;component/myimage.png" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

But, one suggestion: the button automatically resize with his content.